# No tf from some link to some link

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I am working on [OpenMANIPULATOR-X](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/openmanipulator_x/overview/). Problems showed up as I try to use RViz. Error occurred to Robot Status showing `No tf from some link to some link`.

I know `joint_state_publisher` should be responsible for this and as I tapped command `rostopic list`, the topic `joint_states` is listed. The same happens to the node `joint_state_publisher` when I gave the command `rosnode list`.

However, when I input `rosrun tf view_frames`,I get a frame with only two links which indicates obviously that my `joint_state_publisher` is not working properly.

So I am really in need of someone who can help with this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408482/no-tf-from-some-link-to-some-link/) by [marvelousluke](https://answers.ros.org/users/121802/marvelousluke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2022-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-26**:\

1. It would be more helpful to see the actual message instead of "some link" in `No tf from some link to some link`.
2. Please edit your question and add a link to the repository you followed for the package installation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-27**:
Just a quick note: `joint_state_publisher` publishes `JointState` msgs, it does not broadcast TF transforms. That's `robot_state_publisher`'s job.

And actually, if you have a "robot driver" node, I would not expect a `joint_state_publisher` instance in the node graph (unless it's used to combine different topics into a single one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so thankful for your answer.Actually I made a stupid mistake.I forgot to push that start button in Gazebo...anyway thank you for your answer again!

---

Originally posted by [marvelousluke](https://answers.ros.org/users/121802/marvelousluke/) with karma: 20 on 2023-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0